# How to rename and publish existing local ontologies?

Tags: protege

If I want to change standard local ontology IRI on protege with, for example, [purl.org](https://purl.org)
I found this [image]

Any better way to do it?
And because my data is local what is the right way to publish it. Can you tell me more about purl.org - is it optimal solution?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the local IRI you might open the .ttl file with your text editor change the Base IRI. You will find at the top of the file @base http:/purl.org. Then save and open with protege. If you change the base Name in the Protege you will probably only change the name of new entries.